On the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$
Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number, and $\left\{ \cdot \right\}$ denotes the fractional part function. We have focused on how $\left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$ distributes in this MO question. And now I am interested in the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$.
The above question mentions that, I quote, there is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of Hausdorff dimension $1$, such that the corresponding sequence is bounded away from $0$, which means the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$ must diverge.
Though we cannot tell the exact distribution of $\left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$ yet, it might be reasonable to suspect that the convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$ have been fully settled, just as the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sin( n! \pi \alpha )$.
Sadly, I exhaust my scope of search without finding a similar result. As Hanson points out, considering a specific case, such as $\alpha = \pi$, would be unbearably hard. Therefore, it is natural to ask if there exists such a value that the series converges and te4’s comment confirms this as it turns out to be a problem in CIIM 2024. I sketch the solution due to emi3.141592 here for the integrity of this problem.

$\mathrm{e}$ plays well in $\left\{ n! \alpha \right\}$ since $\mathrm{e}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$, which cancels with $n!$ leaving a pleasant term $n!\cdot \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac 1{k!}$. However, it diverges as the harmonic series does, since every term is dominated by $\frac{1}{k+1}$. We imitate the structure of the infinite sum of $\mathrm{e}$, deleting most of the terms to make it converge. In particular, it is easy to prove that $\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2^k)!}$ converges. In fact, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\{  n!\cdot \alpha \right\} \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{k!}{2^n !} \right)< \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{2^{kn}} \right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2^{n}}-\frac{1}{2^{n(2^n-1)}} \right)<1.$$Consider the set $$\left\{ \left. \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{(2^k)!} \, \right| a_k \in \{0,1\} \right\}.$$Clearly the series converges at the numbers in this set. Moreover, there are uncountably many elements, hence an irrational one exists.

It is a rigorous proof of existence. But I greedily wonder if there is a constructive example. In spite of the huge gap impeding  us to reach a proof, could we heuristically conjecture an explicit set of irrational numbers whose corresponding series converge? For example, we expect $\pi$ not in this set.
Moreover, I still wish to request for references to this series.
Any advice is welcomed.

If I recall correctly, distribution of the sequence ${n!\pi}$ is closely related to the problem of whether $\pi + e$ is irrational, which is a fairly hard open problem. As such I'm guessing this is not something we understand very well.

@JamesEHanson Thanks for your comment. I might have greedily expected too much. However I want to know if there is some partial progress. I will edit my question to be more applicable.

See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u1120788h3421811p32954781

The set of irrationals $\alpha \in [0,1]$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { n! \alpha}$  converges is dense, since we can pick a single $\alpha_0$ where this works and add any rational number to it.

Also, by independence, the set of $\alpha$ where it converges will have Lebesgue measure zero.  Given the sum up to a fixed $M$, there exists $N>>M$ sufficiently large such that the following sets are almost independent:  ${\alpha>0: { M!\alpha}<\frac{1}{2}}$ and ${ \alpha>0:{N!\alpha}<\frac{1}{2}}$. Generate sequences $N_1, N_2, \ldots$ and $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2,\ldots$ which control the error away from independence.  Also, $\epsilon_{i+1} >0$ will depend on $N_i$.  The set of $\alpha$ such that ${N_i \alpha} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ infinitely often will have measure 1.

The last line above should say: "The set of $\alpha$ such that ${ N_i ! \alpha } \geq \frac{1}{2}$ infinitely often will have measure 1 by Borel-Cantelli."

How does this differ from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481321/the-convergence-domain-of-the-function-sum-nx ?

@GerryMyerson I am so sorry that I didn't find this post, and stackexchange didn't suggest it either when I write this question. Thanks a lot for your pointing out.
